# How to change the outlining hover color in VS 2010?

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2010, colors, highlighting, outlining

If i hover over the thin vertical bar on the left, it highlights the entire scope of the block that's to the right. When this scope is large, my entire screen flashes white (a consequence of my custom color scheme). Is there a way to change that color? i don't recall there being one when i made the theme.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's `Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Collapsible Region`.  The foreground color is the highlight on the margin, and the background color is the highlight in the text area.

Comment: Fantastic - changed the foreground and background colors to Automatic, and no more flickering/flashing!